# VUE DropDownList cascadeFrom not working

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui

I`ve been learning to vue + Kendo UI.

I suffered a bit today again.

I tried many methods, still I failed to get the working.

Kendo UI: 2018.2.516

vue: 2.5.2

```
<kendo-datasource ref="jobtitleData"
                :schema-data="'data'"
                :transport-read-url="jobTitleService">
</kendo-datasource>
<kendo-dropdownlist ref="jobtitleList"
                    :data-source-ref="'jobtitleData'"
                    :data-text-field="'name'"
                    :data-value-field="'id'">
</kendo-dropdownlist>

<kendo-datasource ref="jobLevelData"
                :schema-data="'data'"
                :serverFiltering='true'
                :transport-read-url="jobLevelService">
</kendo-datasource>
<kendo-dropdownlist ref="jobLevelList"
                    :data-source-ref="'jobLevelData'"
                    :data-text-field="'name'"
                    :data-value-field="'id'"
                    :placeholder="'Select Job Level'"
                    :cascadeFrom="'jobtitleList'"
                    :autoBind='false'>
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following plunker example, which demonstrates cascading DropDownLists.

*Tha answer from telerik bbs
https://www.telerik.com/forums/vue-dropdownlist-cascadefrom-not-working#XsNTjcBQhkWCUzR0JIBYxw*